# Old CSS showing up?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome

I had changed the CSS within my styles.css, I'm using Visual Studio and when I run the website and inspect element it shows the old CSS is being used, however I've changed the CSS completely to have no CSS and also saved the file and re-ran the website but still I get the same old CSS.

Is this a common problem? Does my browser (Google Chrome) cache the CSS by any chance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All browsers cache CSS but you can easily clear the cache while reloading the page. This is called a 'hard refresh'. To do this, you can use one of these keyboard shortcuts:

To perform a hard refresh on Windows, *do not* simply press `F5` or `Control + R`. 
Instead hold down `Control + Shift + R` or `Control + F5` or `Shift + F5`.

To perform a hard refresh on a Mac, hold down `Command + Shift + R`.

In most browsers, pressing F5 more than once is enough to clear the cache of the page you are reloading.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is, as you say, being cached. On Windows, try updating your site by CTRL+SHIFT+F5 or on Mac CMD+SHIFT+R in order to load everything again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using google chrome .. so to load the whole page and replace the cached files(css - jquery .. ) press ctrl + F5.

Answer (score 0):

use f5 or clear the cache memory of chrome . This problem must be due to old existing css file that we need to remove . And yes this is a common problem with simple solution . Hope this is helpful to you..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer doesn't add any new information to this question. If you missed adding something, you can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73002700/edit) to improve it, but simply posting an answer with the same content as other existing answers isn't allowed. See this [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) on what types of answers get deleted by the community and bots.

Answer (score 0):

use ctrl+f5 to clear the cache memory of chrome, like Jasha stated or/ and

Another solution will be to suffix a timestamp/ version number to the css link in file, to make it look different to the browser caching algorithm. so while css files ignore query parameters, it still changes the request and this will also cause something new to be cached.

Finally if you control the webserver you can set cache expire as well

Answer (score 0):

I know sometimes cause of cache support at your hosting or browser css files are not loading yet the old ones.

The solutions above like keep pressing Shift + F5 and other key combinations are the correct ones but sometimes they do not work !

My suggestion here is what I am always using to test css style definitions...

-using css definitions inline at webpage to see effect.

As you know browsers have processing order like this :

1. Inline - by using the style attribute inside HTML elements
2. Internal - by using a  element in the  section
3. External - by using a  element to link to an external CSS file

So for testing you may use inline then remove it.