# CSS sheet in visual studio doesn't match CSS sheet in browser

Tags: css, visual-studio, google-chrome

I'm having trouble with my CSS style sheet in my web form.  Specifically, when I edit my img opacity and save the CSS sheet within VS, I then test my markup code in chrome and when I inspect the element in the browser, the browser points to the correct CSS sheet, but the opacity still shows my old value from the style sheet.
I've tried saving my project and rebuilding my solution in Visual Studio with the new img settings, and closing/reopening Chrome, no luck.

```
//Fonts.CSS Visual Studio CSS Sheet
img{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```
//Fonts.CSS when inspecting image element within chrome browser
img{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: could be a lot of different reasons: cache, wrong file, (supressed) build errors? did you try another browser? are you working on a WordPress site?

Comment: Yes, I've tried microsoft edge as well, no luck. I'm not working on a WordPress site.

Comment: SOLVED: I found the answer on another post here....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772528/old-css-showing-up/31772547

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I was able to clear my browser cache and it fixed the problem.

**In Chrome**

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More.
3. Click More tools and then Clear browsing data.
4. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select All time.
   Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the
   boxes.
5. Click Clear data.

Comment: You can also ask friends and family to try the code for the first time on their machines if you for some reason like to know your history.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with a hard reset of my browser

From another user: [Old CSS showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772528/old-css-showing-up/31772547)

"To perform a hard refresh on Windows, do not simply press F5 or Control + R. Instead hold down Control + Shift + R or Control + F5 or Shift + F5."